# Cardinality between d-systems and sigma-algebras

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I was currently reading the blogpost https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2019/10/06/the-monotone-class-theorem/ and am having trouble understanding some parts of the proofs (Theorem 4 and 8).

The author concludes in both cases something I don't understand (which is kind of the same in both cases, so I'll state my problem regarding theorem 4).

''As ${\sigma}$-algebras are also d-systems, the inequality ${\mathcal F\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal E)}$ is immediate. ''(${\mathcal F}$ is a d-system)

But I understand it that the set of $\sigma$-algebras is ''smaller'' (in a cardinal sense), meaning every $\sigma$-algebra is a d-system but not every d-system is a $\sigma$-algebra.

And wouldn't that mean that the set of $\sigma$-algebras is a subset of d-systems?
But why, if this is true, is then a set of d-systems a subset of $\sigma$-algebras? (I get that this could be case, but why is it the case here?)

Where is my logic wrong (or what part do I miss, that makes the quoted statement obvious)?

Comment: You seem to be confusing the objects in play here. $\mathcal{F}$ is not the collection of all $d$-systems, it's a particular $d$-system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this might ease my distraughtness a bit. Might you (or someone else) explain why the ''inequality ... is immediate.''?

Comment: That's hard to say when you haven't defined what $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ are (I mean... they're supposedly related in some way).

Comment: Okay... so looking through the blogpost... $\mathcal{F}$ is the smallest $d$ system contain $\mathcal{E}$. However, $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{E}$. In particular, it is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{E}$. Thus, $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{E})$.

Comment: I don't see the last step. Okay, $\mathcal{F}$ is the smallest d-system containing $\mathcal{E}$. $\sigma(E)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{E}$, but why does that mean that$\mathcal{F}$ is $\subseteq$ $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$?

Comment: The second to last sentence should definitely read "in particular, it is a d-system containing $\mathcal{E}$," instead.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up a lot.